# iphone programmatically block caller ID?

Tags: iphone

Since *67 doesn't work when embedding in phone links is there a way to programmically block caller ID from an application?

Comment: Thanks, I just filed a bug report to apple.

Comment: Hey stelmate,

Have you or anyone find a way to do that? Or is it still impossible to programmatically change the caller id settings of your iphone when making a phone call from an iphone app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way in the API to interact at all with telephone features except for launching the phone app via a `tel:` URL. As always, if you have a product need for it you should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a bug report with Apple explaining why you need it.